# How to alter the default value of a column in a Sequel migration?

Tags: ruby, migration, database-migration, sequel

I have a user table. I'm trying to change the default Integer value of a column from 0 to 1.

So far, the only method I can come up with is dropping and adding the column with the updated default in a separate migration. But I don't want to have to do this, because that would lose data in pre-existing tables. I haven't been able to find the answer online.

Is there a Sequel way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than ask us to write a tutorial describing everything you could possibly need to know, we need you to describe what you've tried, and why it didn't work. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)".

Answer (score 5):

How about [`set_column_default`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/schema_modification.rdoc#set_column_default)?

```
alter_table :foo do
  set_column_default :bar, 1
end
```